# Unsure which type of list to choose?

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm not that experienced with Java(but learning) data structures and wasn't sure what type of list to choose. My problem is I'm creating a socket service that takes data and checks it against a list, if it doesn't exist then it passes the data on to be processed and added the data ID number to a list so that same data will not be processed again(the service thats processing the data does not know if duplicate work is there or not so this is acting as a filter).

I read that arraylist is fast but I just realized that it requires me to know the size of the list before, which I don't as it keeps growing(it will surely hit several billion items).  I thought I would just use old fashion integer[] but thought I would ask if there was a better way.

There are few specifics related to my process, my data itself is complex but for the lookup I'm converting the data into a hashcode and checking against that so all my data is Integers(positive/negative) and the servicing of the client requests is done via a runnable so   if there's something I can do to make the data more efficient I can do that(I was thinking since its all Integers maybe sorting it every so often to make the loopups faster?).  Is integer[] good enough or is there anything better?

Comment: I hope it doesn't hit more than 2,147,483,647 items. Then you will have a bigger problem than which type of list to choose.

Comment: @Jeffrey I'll keep my fingers crossed it doesn't :-)

Comment: You should probably use a Set instead of a List to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ID is a number or a string, you could use a `HashSet<IDType>`, where `IDType` is the type of the ID (e.g. `int`).  This ensures optimal search time and every element is stored only once.

ArrayList would work too, but to search in it you will have to traverse the whole list (potentially, in a worst-case scenario), comparing each and every element.

Answer (score 2):

```
it will surely hit several billion items
```

I highly doubt that.  That'll be gigabytes of data.

If you really have billions of items, I'd recommend persisting them in a database rather than memory.  You're certainly allowed to cache a subset in memory to make some queries faster, but the long-term solution is a database that will preserve values even if the server goes down.

A database query to check and see if an ID exists will only cost milliseconds.  I think it's a better long term solution than storing them in-memory.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are trying to check for precious items then either ways you will have to store all the items. I would suggest the use of a `HaspMap`. Also, You could use multiple `hashmaps` if one might not be sufficient.

You can easily check by doing

```
if(map.containsKey(blah))
    //Do something
```

Use more than one `hashmap` if you think the items can be differentiated based on something. That might be faster.
Also, since the items are this big, I would suggest the use of a `LinkedHashMap` along with the `HashMap` to do some caching. This would speed up the process as the `LinkedHashMap` would store the frequently occurring items in its priority Q.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already hashing the data, why not use one of the hashed collections e.g. HashSet or HashMap rather than a list?